# Benchmarking channels with a simple ping pong test

Tags: go

I have a simple 2 file go application.  I am trying to benchmark ping and pong messages on 2 channels.

The goal is to run the benchmark to see how many back and forth ping and pong can be done (that is why I am passing the attempts so the benchmark can keep running at different inputs)

For some reason locally it is only displaying this when I run it:

```
go build
./main
```

Output:

```
ping
pong
ping
pong
ping
pong
ping
pong
ping
```

Why does it end after so little iterations?

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    PingPong(1000)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(input)
    fmt.Println("done!")
}
```

ping.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PingPong(attempts int) {
    pingCh := make(chan string)
    pongCh := make(chan string)

    go pinger(pingCh, pongCh)
    go ponger(pingCh, pongCh, attempts)

    pingCh <- "ping"
}

func pinger(pingCh chan string, pongCh chan string) {
    for {
        _ = <-pingCh
        fmt.Println("ping")
        pongCh <- "pong"
    }
}

func ponger(pingCh chan string, pongCh chan string, attempts int) {
    counter := 0
    for {
        msg := <-pongCh
        fmt.Println(msg)
        counter++
        if counter == attempts {
            fmt.Println(counter)
            break
        }
        pingCh <- "ping"
    }
}
```

ping_test.go

```
package main

import "testing"

func benchmarkPingPong(i int, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        PingPong(n)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return values from `fmt.Scanln`. You can't scan into a non-pointer argument.

Answer (score 2):

`fmt.Scanln` needs a pointer:
Use this:

```
fmt.Println(fmt.Scanln(&input))
```

This works for me:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    PingPong(1000)
    var input string
    fmt.Println(fmt.Scanln(&input))
    fmt.Println("done!")
}

func PingPong(attempts int) {
    pingCh := make(chan string)
    pongCh := make(chan string)

    go pinger(pingCh, pongCh)
    go ponger(pingCh, pongCh, attempts)

    pingCh <- "ping"
}

func pinger(pingCh chan string, pongCh chan string) {
    for {
        _ = <-pingCh
        fmt.Println("ping")
        pongCh <- "pong"
    }
}

func ponger(pingCh chan string, pongCh chan string, attempts int) {
    counter := 0
    for {
        msg := <-pongCh
        counter++
        fmt.Println(msg, counter)
        if counter == attempts {
            fmt.Println(counter)
            break
        }
        pingCh <- "ping"
    }
}
```

output:

```
...
ping
pong 999
ping
pong 1000
1000
```

Comment: I just noticed that, but no change anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it wasn't working is that I moved the files out from main.go to ping.go.
When I ran go build, it created different binary name ./pingpong but I was still running the old binary!